# why df vs lsblk command have different results?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, df

so this is the situation:

I had this hardDrive of `500GB`, on my server and tried to upgrade it to a `2T` HardDrive,

after the upgrade result of `lsblk` has changed while df still returns same results.

```
df -h:

/dev/xvdf6      493G  472G     0 100% /root/external


lsblk:

xvdf6 202:86   0     2T  0 disk /root/external
```

so why the size of the drive is different if I use `lsblk` vs `df` commands?

I'm doing some heavy processing, and data in harddrive will go over 500GB, so what happens then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **block device** is now 2TB, but the **filesystem** still has its old size. You need to resize it, e.g. using `resize2fs` - increasing size can be done online.

The steps are these (assuming this is the last partition on the block device):

- First use fdisk or friends to extend the partition,
- then use the resize tool for your file system (`resize2fs` for ext{2,3,4}) to resize the file system.

You don't need to stop your processes, if you use a file system, that can grow online (such as ext{2,3,4} or ocfs2)

Comment: mate could you please demonstrate with an example? also do I have to stop all my processes ?

Comment: @nafas - it's actually quite easy (assuming this is the last partition on the block device): First use fdisk or friends to extend the partition, then use the resize tool for your file system (resize2fs for ext{2,3,4}) to resize the file system. You don't need to stop your processes.

Comment: thx mate, very helpful, btw it would be nice if you edit your answer and add the last comment into it ( for other people to use),  :)

Comment: @nafas: Done so.

Answer (score 2):

Additional info, when you resizing using `resize2fs` you face this kind of error

```
$ resize2fs /dev/yourpartition
...
resize2fs: Read-only file system While checking for on-line resizing support
```

You need to remount it and do it again

```
$ mount -o remount /dev/yourpartition
$ resize2fs /dev/yourpartition
...
The filesystem on /dev/yourpartition is now 976562 (4k) blocks long.
```

reference [here](https://www.incredigeek.com/home/resize2fs-read-only-file-system-while-checking-for-on-line-resizing-support/)